# Can we preserve the request URL in OIDC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, openid-connect, auth0

We are integrating OIDC flow for our legacy ASP.NET webforms application. Currently when a user tries to access a page behind the login wall we send them to the login page and then after login get them back to the page they were trying to access. How can this be achieved with OIDC? The State parameter seems to be managed by .Net so I'm unable to override that.
Right now we can only send them to one callback page post login which is the landing page/ home page.

Answer (score 1):

Try to see if the solution presented here will work for you?

[Adding parameters to the OpenID Connect Authorization URL](https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/adding-parameters-to-openid-connect-authorization-url/)

Also, do make sure you don't create an open redirect vulnerability, see:

- [Preventing Open Redirection Attacks (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/security/preventing-open-redirection-attacks)

Comment: Thanks Tore.. I'm able to pass the parameters but then not sure how to retrieve them back in the Claims

Comment: Do you see the parameter sent back to the client application in the raw HTTP requests? do check this using tools like Fiddler.

Comment: No I don't see it.

Comment: Can somene suggest how to retrieve the set parameters from OwinContext?